# Are detective stories a part of Science Fiction and fantasy site?

Tags: support, scope

Can I include questions about detective stories in this site? If not, on which site can I post them?

Comment: You could try the proposed Literature SE (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature). Example questions can be asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe. As taken from [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e);

> 1. If it's marketed as SF, it's on-topic.
> 2. If magic, futuristic science or technology, alternate history, or other [sf-nal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction)
>      concept is an important part of the overall plot, it's on-topic.
>      (*Alice in Wonderland*, *Clockwork Orange*, etc.)
> 3. If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.
> 4. If it's set in an on-topic universe, it's on-topic.
> 5. If you're not sure it's SF but you think a good case can be made for it, it's on-topic.
> 6. If there is a minor supernatural element (e.g. a fortune teller's prediction comes true, or someone sees a ghost, or a story for
>      children involving anthropomorphic animals) but it's just a throwaway
>      plot element that's not particularly relevant to the question, it's
>      off-topic.

So if the story contains elements of science fiction or fantasy, you might be able to ask it here.

If the story in question has been turned into a film or TV series, you may want to take a look at [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and try there.

Answer (score 2):

### Are "detective stories" on topic?

Per the site's [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), detective stories are **not on topic** for the site **unless they contain elements that are science fictional or in some way fantastical:**

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted
>   towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes
>   questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

You may wish to note that [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/can-i-ask-about-sherlock-holmes-books) specifically asked about whether the Sherlock Holmes stories are on topic. The overwhelming vote was that they are not.

### Where can I ask them?

On-site there's nothing to stop you raising it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Failing that, [Quora](http://www.quora.com) has a good reputation for more general questions, as does [Yahoo Answers](https://uk.yahoo.com/answers)

Comment: No, if I ask a Sherlock Holmes question suppose?

Comment: Yahoo Answers?!

Comment: @Aneek - This has been discussed extensively in chat. The consensus of opinion is that Sherlock is not on topic, albeit one of the short stories contains *some* fantasy content (a man appears to turn into a monkey after drinking a mysterious potion).

Comment: @Aneek - Maybe try http://www.sherlockforum.com/?

Comment: @Wikis - I admit that was just cruel

Answer (score 0):

It depends if they're Sci-Fi or Fantasy detective stories or not. For example [Leviathan Wakes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8855321-leviathan-wakes) by James S. A. Corey is a Detective story set in a Sci-Fi context. Your traditional Agatha Christie detective novels would be off topic.